# Setting output_style for SCSS using Compass in Sinatra app

Tags: sinatra, sass, compass-sass

I'm looking at the Compass-Sinatra [starter file on GitHub](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass-sinatra). Is there a way to set the `output_style` for an scss file in Sinatra? Ideally I would like to set the style to `:expanded` when in development.

I think I'm having trouble understanding how `sass(:"stylesheets/#{params[:name]}", Compass.sass_engine_options )` works and where I can set those options.

Comment: I have a feeling I'm not realizing I still need to watch or compile.

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding the output_style setting to the compass.config file works for changing the output_style. It can either go in the `if defined?(Sinatra)` block or in the configuration block at the bottom of the compass.config file.

```
# compass-sinatra-starter/config/compass.config

if defined?(Sinatra)
  # This is the configuration to use when running within sinatra
  project_path = Sinatra::Application.root
  environment = :development
  output_style = :expanded  # This is where you can set the output_style
else
  # this is the configuration to use when running within the compass command line tool.
  css_dir = File.join 'static', 'stylesheets'
  relative_assets = true
  environment = :production
end

# Or if you wanted to have the output_style set for all environments(?) 

# This is common configuration
output_style = :compressed
sass_dir = File.join 'views', 'stylesheets'
images_dir = File.join 'static', 'images'
http_path = "/"
http_images_path = "/images"
http_stylesheets_path = "/stylesheets"
```

Note: stop/start the server if you change the settings if you don't see the change.

For example, I have a `styles.scss` file in `views/stylesheets/styles.scss` then if I go to `http://localhost:4567/stylesheets/styles.css` I'll get the .scss file compiled in the browser to .css. Changing the `output_style`, start/stop the server the .css `output_style` changes. I don't know if using reloader would work, but it might avoid the stop/start?

I found a couple of other good resources.
Andrew Stewart has a [blog post](http://blog.stwrt.ca/2012/10/26/sinatra-coffeescript-sass) and a [GitHub template](https://github.com/stewart/sinatra-template)

Originally I was trying to learn about media queries in Sass(scss) with Sinatra and found a [great video Ben Schwarz posted](https://vimeo.com/32611202), but it doesn't go into the nitty gritty of setting up. It's more about the media query. Ben also has the [source on GitHub](https://github.com/benschwarz/responsive-sass).

But it seems like [AssetPack](http://ricostacruz.com/sinatra-assetpack/) is the best way to go for serving assets.